# Calculating the number of buyers that are at every hour from 00:00 to 24:00 in the store with tidyverse

Tags: r, datetime, tidyverse, calculation

I need to calculate the number of buyers in a store at each hour of the day. I have reproduced the data from another similar problem but that seemed not to answer the problem I am looking for. I do not want to calculated the length of stay in the store but want to calculate the occupancy of the store, by counting all buyers in the store, at each hour of the day. I need to do this only with tidyverse and lubridate.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107), 
                     Time_in = structure(c(1326309720, 1326309900, 1328990700, 
                                        1328997240, 1329000840, 1329004440, 
                                        1329004680), 
                    class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),  
                    Time_out = structure(c(1326313800, 1326317340, 1326317460, 
                                        1326324660, 1326328260, 1326335460, 
                                        1326335460), 
                    class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = 
                            c("ID", "Adm", "Disc"), 
                    row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Adm and Disc are an action they perform in the shop.

Using the count on year month day hour here makes it possible to scale this to whatever year you want.

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107), 
                     Adm = structure(c(1326309720, 1326309900, 1328990700, 
                                       1328997240, 1329000840, 1329004440, 
                                       1329004680), 
                                     class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),  
                     Disc = structure(c(1326313800, 1326317340, 1326317460, 
                                        1326324660, 1326328260, 1326335460, 
                                        1326335460), 
                                      class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = 
                  c("ID", "Adm", "Disc"), 
                row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attachement du package : 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
by_hours <- df %>%
  gather(key = Type, Time, 2:3)

by_hours
#>     ID Type                Time
#> 1  101  Adm 2012-01-11 20:22:00
#> 2  102  Adm 2012-01-11 20:25:00
#> 3  103  Adm 2012-02-11 21:05:00
#> 4  104  Adm 2012-02-11 22:54:00
#> 5  105  Adm 2012-02-11 23:54:00
#> 6  106  Adm 2012-02-12 00:54:00
#> 7  107  Adm 2012-02-12 00:58:00
#> 8  101 Disc 2012-01-11 21:30:00
#> 9  102 Disc 2012-01-11 22:29:00
#> 10 103 Disc 2012-01-11 22:31:00
#> 11 104 Disc 2012-01-12 00:31:00
#> 12 105 Disc 2012-01-12 01:31:00
#> 13 106 Disc 2012-01-12 03:31:00
#> 14 107 Disc 2012-01-12 03:31:00

by_hours %>%
  mutate( 
    Time = ymd_hms(Time),
    year = year(Time),
    month = month(Time),
    day = day(Time),
    hour = hour(Time),
  ) %>% 
  count(year, month, day, hour)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>     year month   day  hour     n
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1  2012     1    11    20     2
#>  2  2012     1    11    21     1
#>  3  2012     1    11    22     2
#>  4  2012     1    12     0     1
#>  5  2012     1    12     1     1
#>  6  2012     1    12     3     2
#>  7  2012     2    11    21     1
#>  8  2012     2    11    22     1
#>  9  2012     2    11    23     1
#> 10  2012     2    12     0     2
```

Created on 2018-07-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: sorry, just copied the example without realizing it is Adm - Time_in and Disc = Time_out. Hopefully that makes sense. I am not sure by counting year, month, day, hour gives me the number of people in the store at each hour of the day.

Comment: Hey Colin, it gives me an error - Error in count(., year, month, day, hour) : unused arguments (day, hour)